# Custom Compilation Messages

Tags: best-practices

Is there a way to create custom compilation messages? For example

```
\msg{Compiling Chapter 1}
\input{chapter1.tex}
\msg{Finished chapter compilation}
```

Comment: yes use `\typeout` instead of `\msg`

Comment: Although TeX logs the input and closing of files automatically the log will show `(chapter1.tex .....)`

Comment: `\typeout` does the trick. Now is there a way to put those messages to a custom log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in comments you indicated you didn't want to use the log then in the preamble open a new file and write to that

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\mylog
\immediate\openout\mylog=\jobname.mylog

\newcommand\writelog[1]{%
  \protected@write
   \mylog
   {\let\tmp\write\def\write{\immediate\tmp}}%
   {#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\writelog{one}

\writelog{two}



\end{document}
```

will write one and two to a `.mylog` file/

Comment: why are you redefining `\write` in `\writelog`?

Comment: @daleif `\protected@write` is non-immediate write and for `\typeout` you want the immediate form. But `#2` is an unused argument just for dropping in local definitions so I locally redefine `\write` to be immediate/